# How to concatenate multiple columns with colon sign using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like this:

```
head 1kG_MDS6.bim
1   rs2073813   0   753541  A   G
1   rs60320384  0   769223  G   C
1   rs59066358  0   771967  A   G
...
```

I would like to concatenate 1st,4th,6th and 5th column (in that order) separated by ":"

so the output would look like this:

```
1:753541:G:A
1:769223:C:G
1:771967:G:A
```

I tried this:

```
awk ' { print $1 $4 $6 $5 ":" $NF } ' 1kG_MDS6.bim > 1kG_MDS6_SNPs1.txt
```

but it concateneated with ":" just the last two columns

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an output field separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} {print $1,$4,$6,$5}' file
```

Output:

```
1:753541:G:A
1:769223:C:G
1:771967:G:A
```

Answer (score 6):

use printf

```
awk ' { printf "%s:%s:%s:%s\n",$1,$4,$6,$5; } '
```

where

- `%s`  will be replaced by matching argument as a string.
- `\n`  will add a line break for each processed row